# OBB file is not recognised

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I put OBB file manually so I can check if everything is working ok. When I put files in Android/obb folder, it cannot be recognised on the first build. I have noticed that if I restart phone after putting OBB file in obb folder, it starts to be recognised.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a new version, you first have to delete the old folder in your Android/obb directory, **and make sure it is deleted**. Then create a new folder for your app. After that you can copy the new obb file in again. Some phones do require a restart before the old folder is permanently deleted.

Comment: I followed that instructions. Maybe it is because of phone.